# how do i add fixture files in RoR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i wonder how i can add fixture data in RoR3?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as Rails 2.
Also, I suggest you to have a look at factories, as replacement for fixtures.